# Retornar os valores menores que 10 de uma coluna com DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Preciso retornar valores menor que 10 em uma coluna com `DATEDIFF`  e outros entre 10 e 20 da mesma coluna. Alguém pode ajudar-me?

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (MAX(REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM)),105) AS DATA_DEVOLUÇÃO
        ,DATEDIFF ( DAY, MAX(REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM),GETDATE())AS INDISPONIBILIDADE
        ,E.NM_EQUIPTO AS EQUIPAMENTO
        ,NR_PATRIMONIO AS PATRIMÔNIO
        ,CASE 
            WHEN ALMOX.NM_ALMOX = 'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO NOVA LIMA' THEN REPLACE (ALMOX.NM_ALMOX,'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO NOVA LIMA','MG')   
            WHEN ALMOX.NM_ALMOX = 'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO RIO DE JANEIRO' THEN REPLACE (ALMOX.NM_ALMOX,'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO RIO DE JANEIRO','RJ')
            WHEN ALMOX.NM_ALMOX = 'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO MANAUS' THEN REPLACE (ALMOX.NM_ALMOX,'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO MANAUS','AM')    
        END AS FILIAL
FROM V_REMESSA_PATRIMONIO AS REMESSA
INNER JOIN PATRIMON AS P ON REMESSA.CD_PATRIMONIO = P.CD_PATRIMONIO
INNER JOIN EQUIPTO AS E ON E.CD_EQUIPTO = P.CD_EQUIPTO
INNER JOIN EST_ALMOX AS ALMOX ON ALMOX.CD_ALMOX = P.CD_ALMOX
WHERE P.CD_ALMOX IN(4,37,41)
    AND  CONVERT(DATE,REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM) <> '2099-01-01' 
GROUP BY P.NR_PATRIMONIO, E.NM_EQUIPTO, ALMOX.CD_ALMOX, ALMOX.NM_ALMOX
ORDER BY FILIAL;
```

Comment: Poderia postar exemplo do resultado esperado? // Os valores 4, 37 e 41 significam quais almoxarifados, respectivamente?

Comment: @JoséDiz, tudo bem? no sistema esses almoxarifados são de manutenção. Nesse caso em questão preciso da quantidade de equipamentos que estão indisponíveis a menos de 10 dias e outros entre 11 e 20 dias.Grande abraço!

Comment: Como está declarada a coluna REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM?

Comment: Essa coluna @JoséDiz retorna a data de devolução de um equipamento pelo cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jander, para essa totalização não são necessárias algumas das tabelas, que eram utilizadas na consulta original somente para obter descrições.

Eis um caminho:

```
-- código #1 v2
with ctePATRIMON as (
SELECT NR_PATRIMONIO, P.CD_EQUIPTO, P.CD_ALMOX,
       datediff (day, REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM, Current_timestamp) as Indisp
  FROM V_REMESSA_PATRIMONIO AS REMESSA
       INNER JOIN PATRIMON AS P ON REMESSA.CD_PATRIMONIO = P.CD_PATRIMONIO
  WHERE P.CD_ALMOX IN (4, 37, 41)
       AND REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM <> '20990101' 
)
SELECT case CD_ALMOX 
            when 4 then 'xx'
            when 37 then 'xx'            
            when 41 then 'xx' end as FILIAL,
       sum (case when Indisp <= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as Ind0010,
       sum (case when Indisp between 11 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) as Ind1120
  from ctePATRIMON
  group by CD_ALMOX
  order by FILIAL;
```

Somente falta substituir "xx" por "AM", "MG" ou "RJ", dependendo do valor de CD_ALMOX.

O relatório será emitido por almoxarifado. Pode-se modificar o código para emitir por almoxarifado/tipo de equipamento, se necessário.

Comment: Show demais @JoséDiz. Muito obrigado pelo auxílio. Att.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderá transformar sua consulta em uma subconsulta, e a partir dela, obter pela coluna `INDISPONIBILIDADE` os registros menores que 10 e/ou entre 10 e 20.

```
SELECT T.DATA_DEVOLUÇÃO, T.INDISPONIBILIDADE, T.EQUIPAMENTO, T.PATRIMÔNIO, T.FILIAL
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (MAX(REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM)),105) AS DATA_DEVOLUÇÃO
            ,DATEDIFF ( DAY, MAX(REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM),GETDATE())AS INDISPONIBILIDADE
            ,E.NM_EQUIPTO AS EQUIPAMENTO
            ,NR_PATRIMONIO AS PATRIMÔNIO
            ,CASE 
                WHEN ALMOX.NM_ALMOX = 'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO NOVA LIMA' THEN REPLACE (ALMOX.NM_ALMOX,'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO NOVA LIMA','MG')   
                WHEN ALMOX.NM_ALMOX = 'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO RIO DE JANEIRO' THEN REPLACE (ALMOX.NM_ALMOX,'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO RIO DE JANEIRO','RJ')
                WHEN ALMOX.NM_ALMOX = 'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO MANAUS' THEN REPLACE (ALMOX.NM_ALMOX,'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO MANAUS','AM')    
            END AS FILIAL
    FROM V_REMESSA_PATRIMONIO AS REMESSA
    INNER JOIN PATRIMON AS P ON REMESSA.CD_PATRIMONIO = P.CD_PATRIMONIO
    INNER JOIN EQUIPTO AS E ON E.CD_EQUIPTO = P.CD_EQUIPTO
    INNER JOIN EST_ALMOX AS ALMOX ON ALMOX.CD_ALMOX = P.CD_ALMOX
    WHERE P.CD_ALMOX IN(4,37,41)
        AND  CONVERT(DATE,REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM) <> '2099-01-01' 
    GROUP BY P.NR_PATRIMONIO, E.NM_EQUIPTO, ALMOX.CD_ALMOX, ALMOX.NM_ALMOX
    ) T
WHERE T.INDISPONIBILIDADE < 10 
      OR T.INDISPONIBILIDADE BETWEEN 10 AND 20
ORDER BY T.FILIAL;
```

*Obs: Sua consulta possui muitas informações que dificultam gerar um exemplo mínimo. Considere a ideia do que poderá ser feito.*

### Atualização da resposta

De acordo com o que disse, utilizando a CTE, você poderá fazer o `sum` para pegar o total de equipamentos em cada situação.
No final, acrescentei uma forma de saber se o equipamento está nos 10 dias ou entre 11 e 20.

```
WITH CTE_GERAL (DATA_DEVOLUCAO, INDISPONIBILIDADE, EQUIPAMENTO, PATRIMONIO, FILIAL)
AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (MAX(REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM)),105) AS DATA_DEVOLUÇÃO
            ,DATEDIFF ( DAY, MAX(REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM),GETDATE())AS INDISPONIBILIDADE
            ,E.NM_EQUIPTO AS EQUIPAMENTO
            ,NR_PATRIMONIO AS PATRIMÔNIO
            ,CASE 
                WHEN ALMOX.NM_ALMOX = 'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO NOVA LIMA' THEN REPLACE (ALMOX.NM_ALMOX,'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO NOVA LIMA','MG')   
                WHEN ALMOX.NM_ALMOX = 'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO RIO DE JANEIRO' THEN REPLACE (ALMOX.NM_ALMOX,'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO RIO DE JANEIRO','RJ')
                WHEN ALMOX.NM_ALMOX = 'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO MANAUS' THEN REPLACE (ALMOX.NM_ALMOX,'IMOBILIZADO MANUTENÇÃO MANAUS','AM')    
            END AS FILIAL
    FROM V_REMESSA_PATRIMONIO AS REMESSA
    INNER JOIN PATRIMON AS P ON REMESSA.CD_PATRIMONIO = P.CD_PATRIMONIO
    INNER JOIN EQUIPTO AS E ON E.CD_EQUIPTO = P.CD_EQUIPTO
    INNER JOIN EST_ALMOX AS ALMOX ON ALMOX.CD_ALMOX = P.CD_ALMOX
    WHERE P.CD_ALMOX IN(4,37,41)
        AND  CONVERT(DATE,REMESSA.DT_USO_FIM) <> '2099-01-01' 
    GROUP BY P.NR_PATRIMONIO, E.NM_EQUIPTO, ALMOX.CD_ALMOX, ALMOX.NM_ALMOX
    )
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN INDISPONIBILIDADE < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Menor_10',
       SUM(CASE WHEN INDISPONIBILIDADE >= 11 AND INDISPONIBILIDADE <= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Entre_11_20'
FROM CTE_GERAL

--OU apenas informando 1 para verdadeiro e 0 para false em cada registro que não atenda sua condição

SELECT DATA_DEVOLUCAO, INDISPONIBILIDADE, EQUIPAMENTO, PATRIMONIO, FILIAL,
       CASE WHEN INDISPONIBILIDADE < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'Menor_10',
       CASE WHEN INDISPONIBILIDADE >= 11 AND INDISPONIBILIDADE <= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'Entre_11_20'
FROM CTE_GERAL
ORDER BY FILIAL;
```

Comment: Olá @ismael ficou legal desse jeito que vc postou, só esqueci de comentar que preciso da quantidade de equipamentos que estão indisponíveis a menos de 10 dias e outros entre 11 e 20 dias. no caso como usar o count nessa query? Abraço!

Comment: @JanderHelius Neste caso, você quer tudo isso numa única consulta? Ainda com todos os campos que colocou na pergunta?

Comment: Sim @ismael. pois a partir dela irei gerar um relatório para BI.